# How to iterate through nodes of user Preferences in java

Tags: java

In my simple swing application I have created a few textboxes in which a user enters the folder paths for folders the application will use. These are stored using the Preferences API.

At the moment I am having to store the folder paths in an ArrayList as well as the preferences and then iterate through the ArrayList which seems a bit pointless when I *should* be able to iterate through the users preferences for foldernames. How can I retrieve all the preferences for the user at a particular node and iterate through them.

My code:

For the collection of the preferences:

```
public ArrayList<String> folderList() throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException{
        ArrayList<String> AL_folderList=new ArrayList<String>();        
        String PathForBRAVO=null;
        String PathForImpedance=null;
        String PathForHRM=null;
        String PathForDiagnosis=null;
        String PathForBreath=null;

        if(txtPathForBRAVO!=null){
            prefs.put(PathForBRAVO, txtPathForBRAVO.getText());
        AL_folderList.add(txtPathForBRAVO.getText());
        }
        if(txtPathForImpedance!=null){
            prefs.put(PathForImpedance, txtPathForImpedance.getText());
        AL_folderList.add(txtPathForImpedance.getText());
        }
        if(txtPathForHRM!=null){
            prefs.put(PathForHRM, txtPathForHRM.getText());
        AL_folderList.add(txtPathForHRM.getText());
        }
        if(txtPathForDiagnosis!=null){
            prefs.put(PathForDiagnosis, txtPathForDiagnosis.getText());
        AL_folderList.add(txtPathForDiagnosis.getText());
        }
        if(txtPathForBreath!=null){
            prefs.put(PathForBreath, txtPathForBreath.getText());
        AL_folderList.add(txtPathForBreath.getText());
        }           
        Iterator.main(null);
        return AL_folderList;               
    }
```

This gets passed to Iterator

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException {      


        Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);
        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< How to iterate through the Preferences node holding PathForBreath,PathForHRM etc rather than having to iterate through the returned ArrayList from the folderList method????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply iterate over the keys, with the [keys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#keys()) method of `Preferences` .

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException {      


        Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);

        String[] keys = userPrefs.keys();

        for(int i=0; i<keys.length; i++){

           String value = userPrefs.get(key, "No value for this key");

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely related, but I face the problem of only exporting a subset of the the key/value pairs to XML file. There is no easy way to do this.

In case it might be useful, see code below. It temporarily removes entries and adds them back after the export. The entries removed are those that do not start with our particular header string.

Note that these actions will create many PreferenceChange events. It might matter for you.

```java
    /**
     * exports preference values for this node of the chip preferences. Bias
     * values should be stored at the root of the Chip, since nodes branching
     * from this root are not exported, in order to avoid cluttering the bias
     * settings files with other preferences, e.g. for EventFilter's.
     * <p>
     * Biases and other settings (e.g. master bias resistor) are written to the
     * output stream as an XML file
     *
     * @param os an output stream, typically constructed for a FileOutputStream
     * @throws IOException if the output stream cannot be written
     */
    public void exportPreferences(java.io.OutputStream os) throws java.io.IOException {
        storePreferences(); // code puts values to prefs
        try {
            String[] keys = prefs.keys();
            String header=chip.prefsHeader()+"."; // our header string
            HashMap<String,String> removed=new HashMap(); // save the entries temporarily removed
            for (String k : keys) {
                if (!k.startsWith(header)) {
                    removed.put(k, prefs.get(k, null));
                    prefs.remove(k);
                }
            }
            prefs.exportNode(os); // only export biases and chip config prefs, not event filters, AEViewer prefs, etc.....
            log.info("exported preferences node " + prefs+ " filtered for "+header+" keys");
            for(String k:removed.keySet()){
                prefs.put(k, removed.get(k)); // put back the filtered out prefs
            }
        } catch (BackingStoreException bse) {
            bse.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```